# xlwt can't write to xls file?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

Been following a guide to write to xls files and the exmaple used was the following:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
newsheet=wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
newsheet.write('0','0','testing')
wb.save(testing.xls)
```

However I get an error saying:

> ValueError: row index was '0', not allowed by .xls format

This may be a really stupid question (but as guides show this as "valid" does anyone know whats causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two arguments of the `write()` method have to be row and column numbers, not strings:

```
newsheet.write(0, 0, 'testing')
```

FYI, here is the [`write()` method docstring](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Worksheet.py#L1035):

```
def write(self, r, c, label="", style=Style.default_style):
    """
    This method is used to write a cell to a :class:`Worksheet`.

    :param r:

       The zero-relative number of the row in the worksheet to which
       the cell should be written.

    :param c:

       The zero-relative number of the column in the worksheet to which
       the cell should be written.

     ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel very very stupid right now (swear I tried that before and it failed)